# MassTransit timing out when starting bus when using RabbitMQ transport with multiple queues. per process

Tags: .net, rabbitmq, masstransit

We have three Windows services that each have multiple receive endpoints. We do this so that we can keep an eye on message rates for different types of messages, and can have different groups of queues per Windows service to start and stop things independently. We very rarely have messages in flight across all queues so under normal operation everything works fine, however, we've noticed in one of our environments that, particularly when the server restarts and all the apps try to start their bus at the same time, we get timeout exceptions for AMQP operations such as declaring a queue or declaring an exchange.

I believe the problem is that, for every exchange, queue and binding, a new task is created and, for each type of AMQP operation, run in parallel, causing contention. This is in `MassTransit.RabbitMqTransport.Middleware.ConfigureRabbitMqTopologyFilter<TSetting>`:

```
async Task ConfigureTopology(ModelContext context)
{
    await Task.WhenAll(_brokerTopology.Queues.Select(queue => Declare(context, (Queue)queue))).ConfigureAwait(false);

    await Task.WhenAll(_brokerTopology.Exchanges.Select(exchange => Declare(context, exchange))).ConfigureAwait(false);

    await Task.WhenAll(_brokerTopology.QueueBindings.Select(binding => Bind(context, binding))).ConfigureAwait(false);

    await Task.WhenAll(_brokerTopology.ExchangeBindings.Select(binding => Bind(context, binding))).ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

Given that this only seems to be a problem during startup, is there a way to avoid this by replacing the `ConfigureRabbitMqTopologyFilter` with a custom version that declares everything serially? I would prefer to do this rather than have to scale up infrastructure when it doesn't seem to be needed for normal operation, just startup.

Comment: I'd suspect an under-sized broker instance if it can't keep up with the declaration of exchanges, queues, and bindings. Pretty basic stuff, and serially it would take significantly longer to start the bus for people with properly sized brokers.

Comment: Also, under the hood, MassTransit serializes access to the channel, so while these are technically using separate Tasks, they are in fact processed one-at-a-time due to the rules for a single channel. Each receive endpoint has its own channel.

Comment: @ChrisPatterson I was hoping the response wouldn't be that! As I said, there aren't any errors once everything is running. It's just when the apps start, which is why I was hoping there would be a way to address it without changing the infrastructure. But if that's the case, reply with that as an answer and I'll mark it as accepted. Also, out of interest, where is the access serialized?